# ¿Como puedo alinear correctamente una card en bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Hola buenas mi pregunta es saber como solucionar este problema en bootstrap, quiero hacer tres columnas de forma horizontal ya que cuando lo hago me sale de forma vertical agradecere su pronta respuesta

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide(){
    $('#text1').slideToggle();
      
    $('#text2').slideToggle();
    $('#boton').slideToggle();
    }
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".oculto").hide();              
    $(".inf").click(function(){
          var nodo = $(this).attr("href");  
 
          if ($(nodo).is(":visible")){
               $(nodo).hide();
               return false;
          }else{
        $(".oculto").hide("slow");                             
        $(nodo).fadeToggle("fast");
        return false;
          }
    });
}); 
</script>
<style>
      .red
      {
        color: white;
        background-color: red;
      }
      .green
      {
        color: white;
        background-color: green;
      }
      .blue
      {
        color: white;
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 red">
          Hello world
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 green">
          Hello world
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
          <br />
          <div class="card-columns">
          <div class="card" style="max-width:319px;">
            <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />

            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
              <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
              <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card" style="max-width:319px;">
            <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />

            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
              <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
              <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card" style="max-width:319px;">
            <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />

            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
              <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
              <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>



 <style type="text/css">
 .carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 460px;
}
.carousel-inner{
 height: 400px;
}
.card{
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 400px
}
p.saltodepagina
{
page-break-after: always;
}
img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
img { *width: 100%; }

</style>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: lo que quieres es que queden en fila?  uno al lado de otro? y que version bootstrap usas?

Comment: tiene un concepto erroneo de los `col- * -*`, ellos funcionana de otra forma por eso que no logras saber que poner en las clases y se forma así tus card

Comment: Si lo que quiero hacer es que quede en una fila horizontal pero me sale en forma vertical y no se como puedo solucionarlo

Comment: oka voy a interntar expolicar en una repuesta la solucion y el porque el sistema de rejillas

Comment: ok gracias men estare esperanto tu respuesta

Comment: Si usas grids entonces  no debes de emplear css para limitar su tamaño, debes emplear las clases que se tienen en la documentación

Comment: En realidad el css lo puse porque vi un tutorial pero no lo estoy usando en el div card

Comment: lo de hellow word no eso ignoralo yo quiero que salga tipo asi de manera horizontal: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns

Comment: Ahí deje un explición.

Answer (score 0):

Sergio.
Mira yo uso bootstrap v3

Te podría ayudar esta parte:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  Hello world
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  Hello world 2
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  Hello world 3
            </div>
    </div>
```

También tengo esta libreria .css para los grid, es de bootstrap v4, pero ayuda a mejorar el comportamiento de los grids, claro no debería de trabajarse así pero te podría funcionar. "bootstrap-grid.css"

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Yo uso el bootstrap v4 pero la parte de mi duda no son las columnas si no los cards-columms en la parde del div

Answer (score 0):

debes cambiar el `display` a block para la clase `.card` para extra small (@media xs)

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-columns .card {
      display: block;
  }  
}
```

[el ejemplo funcionando lo puedes ver aca](https://jsfiddle.net/jwhxdhys/7/)

Comment: No entiendo te refieres a que agregue eso dentro de la libreria de bootstrap.css?

Comment: dentro de las etiquetas <style></style> en tu main, como complemento al css que ya tienes

Comment: Que raro agrego lo que me dices y no me sale nada todo igual

Answer (score 0):

Bueno partiendo por lo primero este ejemplo esta hecho con bootstap 4, en esto hay que tener claro algo bootstrap trabaja con un sistema de rejillas segun el tamaño de pantallas definidas que son 4 resoluciones:

Resolución LG: mas de 1200px
Resolución MD: a pertir de 992px
Resolución SM:a partir de 768 px
Resolución XS:por debajo de la cifra SM

Con esto en cuenta bootstrap ademas deja un modelo de 12 rejillas o sea divide cada una de estas resoluciones en 12 partes iguales.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row col-xs-12">
<div class="col-xs-1 border">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 border">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 border">3</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 border">4</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 border">5</div>
<div class="col-sx-1 border">6</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 border">7</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 border">8</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 border">9</div>
<div class="col-sx-1 border">10 </div>
<div class="col-xs-1 border">11</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 border">12</div>
</div>
</div>
```

En ese ejemplo dividí en 12 partes iguale en fila y lo puse xs ya que el snnipet es pequeño por eso uso xs, entonces entrando en la lógica de bootstrap si quiero dividir en partes iguales ejemplo en 4 partes, simple matemática dividimos 12 en 4 que seria 3: entonces divido en div en col-xs-3 para que queden partes iguales.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row col-xs-12">
<div class="col-xs-3 border">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 border">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 border">3</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 border">4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Esto hace que yo divida en 4 partes iguales y todavía queden en fila.
Entonces como resumen y para que se den una idea cuando yo digo col-xs-12,col-sm-12 ,col-md-12 y col-lg-12 significa que ocupo el 100% de la resolución que representa cada uno.
Por eso que se usa la etiqueta `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">` , eso es para que se adapte 100% a cada uno de los tamaños de dispositivos.

Para tu ejercicios la solucion es:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 text-center bg-success">
            Hello world
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 green text-center bg-primary">
            Hello world
        </div>

        <div class=" row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 justify-content-center align-self-center">
            
           <div class="card col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="max-width:319px;">
                <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="Card image"/>

                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a
                        camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
                    <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="max-width:319px;">
                <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="Card image"/>

                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a
                        camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
                    <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="max-width:319px;">
                <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="Card image"/>

                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a
                        camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
                    <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto ara que tu card se adapten a dispositivos. como lo muestra el snippet de arriba, espero Haberte dejado un poco mas claro como funciona y la solución.Saludos.
PD:Creo que en bootstrap 4 se agregaron mas sistemas de rejillas como xl y otras rejillas para resoluciones mas grandes.
PD: cuando pones `row` en una `class=""`, significa que todo el contenio dentreo de el estara en "fila".

Comment: esta explicación es perfectamente mejorable.

Comment: Gracias men si me salio pero sale muy a la izquierda me gustaria saber como puedo centrarlo

Comment: que quieres centrar , el texto o los cards?

Comment: edito mi codigo para que lo centre

Comment: simplemente añadi al div que contiene los card las clases `justify-content-center align-self-center` , avisame si te funciona @SergioML

Comment: Tendria que quedar asi?... <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 justify-content-center align-self-center">... si es asi entonces no me funciona

Comment: muy raro yo a mi me funciona porque no tengo ningun css externo aplicado, mira bien tus css agregado , que no afecten a tus cards.

Comment: Yo si tengo css externo pero no veo nada que afecte... no sabes alguna solucion a este problema?

Comment: ese el mismo css que esta arriba cierto?

Comment: el css que esta llegando al cierre del body , hay algo de css que afecta al card lo estas llamando como `.card` , esa es la clase que tiene bootstrap y la estas colocando abajo a lo mejor es eso.

Comment: Si me percate de eso lo quite y sigue igual... tendrias alguna otra solucion? Te lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: no s eque podra ser en realidad tendrias que mostrar todo el codigo html que tienes y yo te lo modifico, lo pruebo en mi pc y veremos. pero no se como se comparte archivos, trata de subirlo para que yo lo descague y te lo veo vale? solo el html que forma esos cards

Comment: Buenas hice otro post donde doy mas detalles y subi mi codigo completo te agradeceria mucho que le des un ojo y me ayudes a encontrar una solucion gracias: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146869/como-puedo-centrar-un-card-en-bootstrap