# ¿Cómo puedo centrar un card en Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy haciendo una página web y lo que quiero hacer es centrar los cards que están en la parte de abajo (lo que esta encerrado en circulo). No logro hacer que se pongan en el centro. Mi código esta hecho en bootstrap 4.

Imagen del problema:
[image: Imagen del problema]

El código:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">

      <div class="card col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="max-width:319px;">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/318x180/" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />

        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
          <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="max-width:319px;">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/318x180/" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />

        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
          <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 .img-fluid" style="max-width:319px;">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/318x180/" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />

        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
          <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: lo vere, estoy haciendo lo ajuste ahora.

Comment: ok muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que las tarjetas tiene un estilo inline: `style="max-width:319px;"` que hace que su ancho máximo sea 319 pixels. Cuando la pantalla es pequeña, no hay problema, pero cuando vas a pantallas grandes (en cuyo caso el ancho puede ser mayor de 960px) se va a quedar un hueco vacío en la parte derecha.

Una solución sería quitar el `style="max-width:319px;"` para que las columnas tomen todo el ancho permitido en cada momento:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">

      <div class="card col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/318x180/" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />

        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
          <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/318x180/" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />

        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
          <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 .img-fluid">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/318x180/" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />

        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
          <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Si no quieres quitar el ancho máximo de 319px y lo que quieres es que se centren, lo que deberías hacer es al `.row` más interno (el que contiene directamente los cards): quitarles todas las clases col-XXX-YY y añadirle como estilo `width: auto; margin: auto auto`.

Al final quedaría así:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="row cards" style="width: auto; margin: auto auto;">

      <div class="card col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="max-width:319px;">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/318x180/" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />

        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
          <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="max-width:319px;">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/318x180/" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />

        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
          <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 .img-fluid" style="max-width:319px;">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/318x180/" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" />

        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
          <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

primero he armado la estructura base de la pagina mostrada, listado de cambios:

1-Crear un div general con la clase `container-fluid` para que tome el 100% del navegador.
2-Crear 3 div con clase `row`, 2 que tomen el 100% del ancho y uno que que se divide despues en 3 divs mas
3-Entonces dentro de los row expresamos las resoluciones a las que queremos que se adapte , en este caso `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12` , e un div
4-Luego dividor el ultimo row en tres partes iguales insertando la clase  `col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4` a cada uno de los tres div, ques estan dentro del ultimo row.
5- Modifique el navbar para que fuera mejor y creo que lo deje como querías.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12" style="background-color:yellow;">
       100%
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    
    <div class="row p-2">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12" style="background-color:yellow;">
       100%
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- Or let Bootstrap automatically handle the layout -->
    <div class="row mx-auto p-3">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="background-color:yellow;">33,3%</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="background-color:orange;">33,3%</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="background-color:yellow;">33,3%</div>  
    </div>
    <br>
 
  </div>
   

</body>
</html>
```

Por ultimo insertamos las etiquetas dentro donde pertenece cada parte que tenias tu en tu código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .carousel-inner img {
            width: 100%;
            max-height: 460px;
        }

        .carousel-inner {
            height: 400px;
        }

        p.saltodepagina {
            page-break-after: always;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        img {
            *width: 100%;
        }

        @media (min-width: 576px) {
            .card-columns .card {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        .container {
            flex-direction: row;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Control the column width, and how they should appear on different devices -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                <!---TU parte de codigo insertada---->
               <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Desplegar Navegacion</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Menu 1
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Menu 2
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </nav>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="row p-2">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
    
                <section class="container">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <!-- Indicators -->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>
    
                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img src="img/slide2.jpg" alt="Ao no exorcist">
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/slide3.jpg" alt="Shingeky no kyojin">
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/slide4.jpg" alt="Fariy Tail">
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <!-- Left and right controls -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </section>
    
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row mx-auto p-3">
    
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="card ">
                    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Card image"/>
    
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a
                            camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
                        <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Card image"/>
    
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a
                            camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
                        <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="card .img-fluid">
                    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Card image"/>
    
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a
                            camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
                        <a href="http://sonarsystems.co.uk" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function showHide() {
            $('#text1').slideToggle();
    
            $('#text2').slideToggle();
            $('#boton').slideToggle();
        }
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $(".oculto").hide();
            $(".inf").click(function () {
                var nodo = $(this).attr("href");
    
                if ($(nodo).is(":visible")) {
                    $(nodo).hide();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $(".oculto").hide("slow");
                    $(nodo).fadeToggle("fast");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Nota en los row donde sale la clase `p-2` eso es un padding, para
>   separa los row y tambien quite el css que afectaba los cards.

Ahora solo te queda agregar tus fotos y script que quieras.Prueba de forma responsiva y veras como se adapta.Ojala te sirva.

Comment: Exactamente en donde estaba el problema? que fue lo que agregaste o quitaste?

Comment: sorry, solo le puse la linea que te dije el otro día el  `justify-content-center align-self-center` en el div que contenia todos los cards,aparte tenias script duplicacod me refiero a que importaste dos veces jquey arriba en el head y al cerrar el body.Tambien quite los `max-with`. El resto lo deje como está.Pero puedes dejar los max-withd si quieres se centrará igual.

Comment: Copio tu codigo si me lo centra y todo pero lo que hice se pone de otra forma... como podria mandarte una imagen por aca para que veas?

Comment: mira esta pagina subes la imagen y genera una url me la pasa para ver [pagina par generar imagen url](https://es.imgbb.com/), no es necesario crearse una cuenta.

Comment: ya mira fijate bien donde dice el logotipo ademas que en la imagen no se pasa a las demas imagenes: https://ibb.co/mvSiHx

Comment: quieres dejar el menu de arriba tal como esta cierto?, o quieres centrar todo?

Comment: voy hacer algo yo ahora , reestructuraré toda tu pagina y editare mi respuesta explicando lo que hice.

Comment: Mira esta imagen: https://ibb.co/mc6PqH asi me tiene que quedar eso lo hice con mi codigo original pero al reemplazar tu codigo sale otra cosa, acaso usas otra libreria o que version de bootstrap usas?

Comment: @SergioML ahi te deje la modificacionde tu sitio si lo quieres integrar eso centra los 3 cardsy quedo maquetado tu página.

Comment: uso bootstra 4 para todo eso

Comment: Listo te deje, el menu listo para que lo veas y edites.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio pero ahora salio otro problema no se porque no muestra las mimagenes en mi carousle yo tengo los nombres correctos y nada mira la imagen: https://ibb.co/ng3hAH

Comment: revisa bien la carpeta y la direcciones del src de la imagenes, que yo cambie el nombre de la carpeta `imagenes`  por  `img`.Lo hice para que me funcionara en mi pc. La otra forma de saber si esta leyendo las imagenes te recomeindo usar el inspeccionar del navegador para ver que error te dá.

Answer (score 0):

Sin meter código adicional podes usar Offsetting de Boostrap:

```css
.borde{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row borde">
  <div class="offset-1 col-10">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 borde">Columna</div>
      <div class="col-4 borde">Columna</div>
      <div class="col-4 borde">Columna</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Agregue el borde para que se entienda

Answer (score 0):

A tu columna establécele lo siguiente en css

```
.col{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center !important;
}
```

Comment: En lo posible, explica brevemente lo que hace tu código. Lee [answer].